# How to increase the duration of an animation outside of the original function?

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, android-animation

I want to increase the duration of the animation outside the original function, meaning that if a button is pressed the animation time should increase and when the button is released the animation time should jump back to normal.

This is the animation:

```
    val animation = arrayOf(-820f).map { translation ->
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stripe, "translationX", translation).apply {
            duration = 600   
            repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
        }
    }

    val set = AnimatorSet()
    set.playTogether(animation)
    set.start()
```

And this is the function for the button when it is clicked:

```
    button.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {

        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {


            when (event?.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        //Increase animation duration to 1200
                }// On click

            }
            when (event?.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                       //Put animation duration back to 600
                }// Released


            }

            return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
        }
    })
```

I need help finding a way to set a new duration time in ACTION_DOWN and set it then back to normal in ACTION_UP.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An `Interpolator` should be used to change animation speed.
For example:

```
val interpolationValue = floatArrayOf(1f)
```

...

```
val set = AnimatorSet()
set.playTogether(animation)
set.interpolator = object : LinearInterpolator() {
    override fun getInterpolation(input: Float)
            : Float {
        return input * interpolationValue[0]
    }
}
set.start()
```

...

```
when (event?.action) {
    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
        interpolationValue[0] = 2f
        //Increase animation duration to 1200
    }// On click
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
        interpolationValue[0] = 1f
        //Put animation duration back to 600
    }// Released
}
```